# Homomorphism between Lie group and transformation groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $M$ be a differential manifold. Let $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ be the set of smooth vector field over $M$. Let $g$ be a finite Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$. Let $G$ be a connected, simply connected Lie group whose Lie algebra is $g$.

Suppose $g$ has the property that $\forall X\in g$, $X$ is complete. We can thus define the transformation $X_t\in\mathrm{Diff}(M)$. The group generated by all such transformations is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$, denoted $H$.

If $\dim g=1$, $\exp(tX)\rightarrow X_t$ defines a homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$.

In general, how do we prove that there exists such a homomorphism?

(in [Kobayashi](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/SUGRA/Kobayashi.pdf), page 13, it is stated that the group $G$ acts locally on $M$, which, I believe, is equivalent to the existence of such a homomorphism. The homomorphism is also used in the proof of lemma 1 on the same page).

Comment: It's not clear to me that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, even when $\dim.g=1$.  For example, if $M=S^1$ and $g$ is the span of the vector field $X(p)= ip$, then I think $G=\mathbb{R}$ while $H=S^1$.

Comment: Much thanks for the example. I’ll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you use the fact that if two Lie groups have the same Lie algebra then their universal covers are isomorphic?

Comment: Let $G, H$ be Lie groups and $\mathfrak{g, h}$ their Lie algebras. If $\Phi: G\to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism it is clear that $d\Phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak h$ is a Lie-algebra homomorphism. This cannot always be turned around, but if $G$ is simply connected then it can: For any Lie-algebra homomorphism $\phi: \mathfrak g\to \mathfrak h$ there is a Lie-group homomorphism $\Phi:G\to H$ integrating this if $G$ is simply connected. For your case your group $G$ is simply connected and $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak h$, so you take as Lie-algebra homomorphism the identity.

Comment: @Jason DeVito, s.harp In my case $H$ is a priori not a Lie group (I’m trying to understand the proof that it can be endowed with a Lie group structure). And yea I’m permitted to use universal covering for Lie groups.

Comment: I see, I was assuming $H$ was already a finite dimensional Lie group.  If I was going to prove the existence of the homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$, I'd probably follow Kobayashi's proof that $H$  really is a Lie subgroup, then use s.harp's argument.  I do *not* think that Kobayashi's local action is equivalent to such a homomorphism (a priori) since the local action is only defined on a neighborhood of $e\in G$.  For $U$ in Koboyashi's book, one can work as follows:  there is an open neighborhood of $0\in T_e G$ for which $\exp|_V:V\rightarrow G$ is a diffeo on its image.  Call the image $U$.

Comment: But in the course of proving that $H$ is endowed with a Lie group structure, it seems that he already assumed this homomorphism (e.g in lemma 1, when he passed from the Lie universal covering to local action)... something is bugging me...

Comment: What you need is called the subgroup-subalgebra correspondence. If $h\subset p$ is a sub-algebra then there is a unique connected Lie subgroup (not necessarily closed) $H\subset P$ having $h$ as its Lie algebra. However this is a finite-dimensional statement, and uniqueness at least might fail if $h$ is infinite dimensional. For finite $h$ it seems reasonable that this statement is true even if $P$ is infinite dimensional, take a look at this write-up I found by googling for example, maybe the proof doesn't need finite dimensionality of $P$.  https://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/liegroups2007/10.pdf

Comment: @s.harp I don’t see how that applies here. The group $H$ in my question is defined purely in term of transformation on $M$ and their composition. It is not necessarily a Lie group (which is a property I cannot assume, since I’m proving it).

Comment: @Learning:  After thinking about it all day, I still don't really see why Kobayashi's $f$ is a homomorphism.  On the other hand, I did find http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LectureNotes/action.pdf, where Theorem 1.11 proves Kobayashi's main result.

Comment: @Learning you are in the situation that you have a big Lie group $\mathrm{Diffeo}(M)$ and a sub-algebra $\mathfrak h\subset \mathfrak X(M)$. Then you look the subgroup $H$ generated by elements $\exp(t\,x)$ for $x\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, this exponential is both the development of vector fields and the Lie-algebra exponential that gives an element of the Lie group (they agree here!). This is exactly the situation in which that correspondence applies. The only issue is that what I've said only works for finite dimensional things, one still needs to show that you can do it here.

Comment: @Jason DeVito thanks. I’ll read the note. There must be some non trivial ingredients looked over. I would have given you the correct-answer check :)

Comment: In his note Meinrenken used foliation to prove that the algebra action integrates to group action, which would give the homomorphism needed in Kobayashi’s. One can find foliation idea in the original proof of Steenrod and Meyers. It’s coherent.

Comment: Glad you liked it.  Feel free to write up your own answer, I don't need the rep.

Comment: Meinrenken constructs a foliation on $G\times M$ corresponding to a Lie algebra $g$ acting on $M$, which gives me a geometric idea of what’s going on. However, when I read “concretely the above argument shows that this is a group action”, I don’t see a connection...

Comment: More specifically, his argument stays inside one leaf $\mathcal{L}_m$, whereas to prove $g(hm)=(gh)m$, I think it’s necessary to have the leaf $\mathcal{L}_{hm}$ under consideration. I’m trying to calculate $g(hm)$ staying inside $\mathcal{L}_m$, but hasn’t found any yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I give a proof idea:

Let $N=G\times M$ and $g_\times$ be the vector field defined by $(g,m)\mapsto(X_{\mathfrak{X}(G)}(g),X_{\mathfrak{X}(M)}(m))$. Then by Frobenius theorem there exists a unique submanifold $\mathcal{L}_m$ passing by $(e,m)$ integrating $g_\times$. We prove that $\mathcal{L}_m\simeq G$ by the first projection, and there exists $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathcal{L}_m)\rightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ a group homomorphism induced by the second projection (which concerns picking a pre-image in $\mathcal{L}_m$ the choice of which which leaves the overall operation invariant). And finally we observe that the composite morphism:

$$G\rightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(G)\rightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(\mathcal{L}_m)\rightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(M)$$

sends $\exp(tX)$ to $X_t$.